# Decoding into recursive ADTs with argonaut

Tags: scala, argonaut

I'm trying to parse json like

```
{
  "element": "string",
  "content": "application/json"
}
```

where `element` decides which type the json is. But my code fails to parse.

http://scastie.org/15213

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import argonaut._, Argonaut._, Shapeless._

case class ArrayAttributes(default: List[StringElement])

sealed trait Element
case class StringElement(content: String) extends Element
case class ArrayElement(attributes: ArrayAttributes, content: List[Element]) extends Element
case class Reference(element: String) extends Element { def content = element }

object Parser {

  def kindDecode[T](
    kinds: Map[String, DecodeJson[T]],
    fail: HCursor => DecodeResult[T] = { c: HCursor => DecodeResult.fail[T]("expected one of ${kind.keys}", c.history) }): DecodeJson[T] = DecodeJson(c =>
    (c --\ "element").as[String].flatMap { kind =>
      kinds.get(kind).map(_.decode(c)).getOrElse(fail(c))
    }
  )

  implicit def elementDecode: DecodeJson[Element] = kindDecode(
    Map(
      "string" -> DecodeJson.of[StringElement].map(identity[Element]),
      "array" -> arrayDecode.map(identity[Element])
    ),
    { c => DecodeJson.of[Reference].decode(c).map(identity[Element]) }
  )

  def arrayDecode: DecodeJson[ArrayElement] = jdecode2L(ArrayElement.apply)("attributes", "content")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer with the current milestone of argonaut-shapeless (`1.0.0-M1`), which has had relevant additions since the `0.3.1` version.

It allows to specify so-called `JsonSumCodec`s for sum types, that drive how the sub-types are encoded / discriminated.

By defining one for `Element` in its companion object, like

```
implicit val jsonSumCodecForElement = derive.JsonSumCodecFor[Element](
  derive.JsonSumTypeFieldCodec(
    typeField = "element",
    toTypeValue = Some(_.stripSuffix("Element").toLowerCase)
  )
)
```

your example just works:

```
> Parse.decodeEither[Element](member)
res1: (String \/ (String, CursorHistory)) \/ Element =
  \/-(StringElement(application/json))
```

`JsonSumCodecFor` above is a type class that provides a `JsonSumCodec` for a given type, here `Element`. As a `JsonSumCodec`, we choose `JsonSumTypeFieldCodec`, that uses a field, `"type"` by default, to discriminate between sub-types. Here, we choose `"element"` instead of `"type"`, and we also transform the sub-type names (`toTypeValue` argument), so that these match the names of the example input.